# Add data to multiple data fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a bit of a problem and I'm hoping you can help. 
I have a site where I have to add students to a database and link them to families assigned to them. Linking the families is okay, I have this done using id numbers which auto increment when you add the family and student. These are on two separate tables within the database.
The problem I'm having is that multiple students can be added to a family but with only one student to be added at any one time.

At the moment I'm adding simply with id numbers but I have to take into account two things. In the student table there is an arrival and departure date (which corresponds with airport arrival date) and in the family table there are six fields, 3 with arrival dates and 3 with departure dates of students already assigned to them.

I need it that the new student added will not add if the arrival dates and departure dates cross over (although an error can come up and it can be over-written if needs be). If the dates don't overlap and the departure date of one of the students is already gone (before Now date) then it will overwrite that. Any help would be appreciated.
I'll include the code that I have for adding and any help you can give would be great or if you want more info then please ask!

```
    require "dbc.php";
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit3']))
    {
        $shid2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_4']);

            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_3']);

            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE student SET shostfamilyid='".$shid2."' WHERE sid ='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'");
            $result = mysql_query($query);

    //if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
            echo "Host Family ID added to student";

    echo "<p>Return To Member Page: <a href='members.php'>Member Page</a>";

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you remove most of that text and just focus on exactly what your problem is? Do you want to know how to create a one-to-many relationship? Do you want to know how to add multiple records at the same time? Do you want to know how to dynamically change table structure with a query? I just can't read that much text at once. Sorry. Maybe someone else will. Or at least break it up into paragraphs. It is just too daunting the way it is.

Comment: Don't overwrite your historic student records, flag them as 'D' departed or deleted (a soft-delete) when they are no longer active. But don't overwrite. Databases are valuable for _history_, _statistics_ and you get these almost for free, just so long as you don't pointlessly bungle it and overwrite the data. How are you going to return a student's lost personal item if you've trashed the record with someone else's details?

Comment: I don't know if you got what I was asking. I'm not overwriting students personal details, the students table itself won't be written to, I wish to write to the family table and only then write the dates of arrival and departure of students. These dates will correspond to arrival and departure dates in the student table. There's actually a lot more that I could have written to clarify but as Buttle has already shown, people won't read it

Comment: I think you are storing duplicate information in the family table, which does not seem necessarry.